# Field extension $k(a)$

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

Well, first I write some definitions:

> Let $K|k$ be a field extension. Then $k(a)$ denotes
>   $$
> k(a)=\bigcap\{F:k\subseteq F \subseteq K \,\ a\in F \}
> $$
>   and is the smallest field of the extension $K|k$ such that $a$ belongs to it.

With  this, and given $a$ in $K$, I set 
$$
\begin{array}{cccc}
\phi:& k[x]&\to & K\\
& p(x)& \to & \phi(p(x))=p(a)
\end{array}
$$
This function is a ring homomorphism, such that $\phi(\alpha)=\alpha, \ \forall \alpha \in k$ and $\phi(x)=a$. What I don't get is the following:

> $$\text{Im}(\phi)\subseteq k(a)$$

I'd appreciate any hint to prove this.

Comment: $k\subset K$, and $a\in K$.

Comment: $k(a)$ contains all powers of $a$. And all products of such a power with an element of $k$. And all finite sums of such products.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

Show that $\mathrm{Im(\phi)}=\{p(a)\ |\ p\in k[x]\}$ is a field that contains $k$ and $a$ and show that every field contains $k$ and $a$ then contains $\mathrm{Im(\phi)}$.

Comment: Very nice hint!